# objective C [self init] hierarchy for multilevel inheritance

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, dynamic, multiple-inheritance

I have class A which inherits class B. And want to achieve something like below. But the init methods get recursive call due to dynamic typecasting. 
Is there any way to achieve such? Any suggestion? (without changing 'init's name in subclass?

```
@interface A : NSObject
@property NSData * data;
@end
```

---

```
@implementation A

- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    /* want to do some default initialization here  
       for this class and all of its subclasses. */
    // ... ... 
    return self;
}

/* This [self init] get recursed. 
   But how can I force this class and all of its subclass to call [self init] above, 
   not to call the subclass's init method. */

- (id) initWithData:(NSData *)d {
    self = [self init];
    self.data = d;
    return self;
}

@end
```

---

```
@interface B : A

@end
```

---

```
#import "B.h"

@implementation B

- (id) init {
    self = [super initWithData:nil];
    // some subclass specific init code here ... 
    return 
}
@end
```

---

Using B,

```
- (void) testInit{
    B * b = [[B alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: "something like below" - like what? "the init methods get recursive call due to dynamic typecasting" - ???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're calling `[self init]` in your implementation which is causing the recursion issue..

Implement this way :

```
- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    //Basic empty init...
    return self;
}

- (id) initWithData:(NSData *)d 
{
    self = [super init]; //<---- check this line.

    if(self)
    {  
        self.data = d;
    }
    return self;
}
```

//If you are looking to write some init code only 1 time the the following can work.....

```
-(void)oneTimeWrittenInitCode:(id)mySelf
{
    //your init code which you wish to write one time goes here...
}    

- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
       [self oneTimeWrittenInitCode:self];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id) initWithData:(NSData *)d 
{
    self = [super init];

    if(self)
    {  
        [self oneTimeWrittenInitCode:self];
        self.data = d;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I knew that. But if I need to do some default init steps in the superclass, and want to call [self init] in the super class. That is the problem. Then it calls the sublcass (dynamic name resolution). But is there any way to prevent it?

Comment: The init(s) written in your super class will automatically be called when you call [super init] in your sub-class's init code.

Answer (score 1):

Look up the "designated initializer" pattern. It describes how to arrange initializer methods and convenience constructors (a.k.a. factory methods) in a class hierarchy.

Comment: The issue is the behavior of designated initializer and its overriding in the subclass. if [self init] or anything like that is overridden, but in the superclass if it any of them is called, it dont call the superclass's one, but the subclass's overrident method.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of designated initilizer pattern mentioned above,

```
#import ”Person.h”

@implementation Person
-(id) initWithAge:(int)theAge AndHeight:(int)theHeight AndName:(NSString *)theName {
  if (self = [super init]){
    _age = theAge;
    _height = thefleight;
    _name = theName;
  }
  return self;
} 

-(id) initwithAge:(int)theAge AndHeight:(int)theHeight {   
  return [self initWithAge:theAge AndHeight:theHeight AndName:nil];
}

-(id) initwithAge:(int)theAge {
  return [self initWithAge:theAge AndHeight:0];
}  

- (id)init {
  return [self initwithAge:0];
}
@end
```

Comment: Naming conventions should conform Apple guidelines
-(id) initwithAge:(int)theAge AndHeight:(int)theHeight
should be replaced with
-(id) initwithAge:(int)theAge height:(int)theHeight
Remove And from method signature.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
- (instancetype) initWithData:(NSData *)d
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
       _data = d;
    }
    return self;
}
```